# VR Unity Raycast is only hitting to one game object, but not on the other game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, gameobject

Currently, I'm trying to setup a raycasting (Oculus controller) but for some reason, i can get the controller to raycast one of my gameobject, but not on the game object next and game object previous.  When I raycast to these two game object (with a box collider), nothing happen.  What I'm doing wrong with my code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ControllerInputNextPrevious : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] model; 
    private int _index;

    void Update() {

        if (OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Button.PrimaryIndexTrigger))

        {
          RaycastGun();
        }
    }
    private void RaycastGun()
        {
            RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(vrTransform.position, vrTransform.forward, out hit))

        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Cube"))

            {
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }

            if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == ("Next"))

            model[_index].SetActive(false);

            _index--;
            if (_index < 0)
            {
                _index = model.Length - 1;
            }

            model[_index].SetActive(true);


            if (hit.transform.gameObject.tag == ("Previous"))

            model[_index].SetActive(false);

            _index++;

            if (_index > model.Length - 1)
            {
                _index = 0;
            }

            model[_index].SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Going to need to see more about the setup. Check which layer they're on. Check if you get the buttons hit with `RaycastAll` to make sure something in front of it isn't stopping it.

Comment: It's on a default layer.  I will try the raycastAll and see what it will do.

Comment: Also make sure that if collider is set as trigger only then you need to query triggers too when raycasting. There’s an optional argument in one of the overloads.

Comment: I have just solved the problem.  It wasn't the code but needed to add the mesh filter to my 3d model to make it work.